# Error Converting Custom Action Condition

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, wix, windows-installer, wix3.10

I have a custom action that is working in Installshield 2009 that I am not sure how to port to WiX.  Syntax looks right to me, according to [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368012(VS.85).aspx), but VS2015 and WiX 3.10.2 are quite unhappy... informing me that **Entity SA' is not defined** in the `Not &SA=3` portion.

I tried wrapping the values in the RHS of the conditions with quotes, to no avail.  I do have a `<Feature Id="SA" ...` defined earlier (was after my custom actions, thought moving it up in the wxs file would help, it did not).

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
<Custom Action="CA_StopClientService" After="StopServices" >((REMOVE="ALL") And (!SA=3)) Or ((Not &SA=3) And (!SA=3))</Custom>
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, I think.  Two options to solve it:

```
<![CDATA[((REMOVE="ALL") And (!SA=3)) Or ((Not &SA=3) And (!SA=3))]]>
```

or

```
((REMOVE="ALL") And (!SA=3)) Or ((Not &amp;SA=3) And (!SA=3))
```

The first might be a little cleaner, in that, you can just write code.  The second just replaces the `&` with `&amp;`.  When I decompiled the msi with dark.exe, it produced code that followed the second form, which is what I ultimately ended up using.  My problem stemmed from actually copying out the condition from installshield while replicating the installexecutesequence.